# Laravel delete job once it fails

Tags: php, laravel, redis, laravel-queue, laravel-jobs

I have a job that times out and once it fails it dispatches another one just like itself so that it can run infinitely and without overlapping. However the job that fails stays in the queue and gets re-tried so I eventually have more than one job running which breaks the whole purpose.

Here is how I handle the failing of the job:

```
use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

public function handle()
{
    //infinite websocket listening loop
}

public function failed(Exception $exception)
{
    $this::dispatch()->onQueue('long-queue');
    $this->delete();
}
```

`$this->delete()` comes from `InteractsWithQueue` trait. What am I doing wrong?

Edit:
I am using horizon for running the jobs, here is the configuration for the custom queue set in `config/horizon.php`

```
'supervisor-long' => [
    'connection' => 'redis-long',
    'queue' => ['long-queue'],
    'balance' => 'simple',
    'processes' => 3,
    'tries' => 1,
    'timeout' => 3600,
],
```

The job that I am dispatching is creating a Thruway client to connect to a web-socket server and subscribe to a channel for updates so I want to run this job forever, but only run one instance of this job at any time. That is why I want it to run once without any tries and once it times out to dispatch another instance that will run and the loop will continue. I couldn't think of a better way to achieve this, is there another way to do this better?

Comment: why in the failed function you dispatch again the job?

Comment: I assume that after first attempt you want to move your job to another queue (long-queue). Jobs are still running on default queue because you don't set max numbers of tries. You can change you queue command like so `php artisan queue:work --tries=1` after that your jobs will be moved to failied_jobs table after first attempt.

Comment: What is the difference between what you are trying to do and what Laravel is already doing?

Comment: Sum of all these comments, what is wrong with using the built in retry functionality?

Comment: @MartinHenriksen Sometimes you may want to move failed jobs to another queue for example queue with some delay or with longer timeout

Comment: This example is fairly simple thou, but i did not get the fact that it was on a different queue

Comment: I have updated the question to provide more information on the context and provide the horizon configuration for the custom queue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that my jobs were not failing so the `failed()` method was not getting executed. Even if you set tries to `tries => 1` within your `config/horizon.php` file, you need to set the `retry_after` value to `0` within your `config/queue.php` file so that the job fails just after it times out. This way your `failed()` methods gets called immediately. Below you can find the final forms of my config files.

`config/queue.php`:

```
'redis-long' => [
    'driver' => 'redis',
    'connection' => 'default',
    'queue' => 'long-queue',
    'retry_after' => 0,
    'block_for' => null,
],
```

`config/horizon.php`:

```
'supervisor-long' => [
    'connection' => 'redis-long',
    'queue' => ['long-queue'],
    'balance' => 'simple',
    'processes' => 1,
    'tries' => 1,
    'timeout' => 3600,
],
```

Comment: Usually the standard is to set retry_after to more than the timeout, so you secure that your job has a chance to execute. I'm not certain that retry_after 0 is a good idea.

Comment: I do not want the job to retry at any point and not setting `retry_after => 0`  adds a delay to the whole process and that delay has to pass until the `failed()` function is called. This configuration yields the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

Found you can actually do this in the `failed` method in a queued job:

```
/**
 * Handle the failing job.
 *
 * @param Exception $ex
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function failed(Exception $ex)
{
    $this->delete();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason why failed is not executed, it is only triggered when a job exceeds it's maximum tries. The flow looks something like this.

```
$job->dispatch(); // try 1
// times out
// retries on try 2 now
// times out
// retries on try 3 now
// max attempt is hit and MaxAttempt exception is thrown
// failed is called
```

This logic is changed if your job actually crashes, this example is only when it runs indefinitely. Where the logic is [handled](https://github.com/illuminate/queue/blob/ccf52a9421c2186fdcda3931b34ba1d3171e40f6/Worker.php#L316).

On your queue definition in config/horizon.php you can define tries.

```
'my-short-queue' => [
    'connection' => 'redis',
    'queue' => ['my-short-queue'],
    'balance' => 'simple',
    'processes' => 1,
    'tries' => 1,
]
```

Comment: So you can choose the solution to limit the retry amount, Milena's comment works great there.

Comment: I am using laravel-horizon to process the queue, so Milena's solution is not applicable